# postgres upgrade from 10.9 to 11.4 failure (aws rds)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, postgis, amazon-rds, postgresql-11

postgres upgrade from 10.9 to 11.4 on aws rds failure with below reason

> Database instance is in a state that cannot be upgraded: PreUpgrade
>   checks failed: The instance could not be upgraded because there are
>   one or more databases with an older version of PostGIS installed.
>   Please upgrade all installations of PostGIS and try again.

i have postgis 2.4.4 installed and command

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;
```

fails with message

> NOTICE:  version "2.4.4" of extension "postgis" is already installed

and command

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO "2.5.1"
```

fails with this message

> extension "postgis" has no update path from version "2.4.4" to version
>   "2.5.1"

Comment: pls select my answer if it helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you that error because there is no upgrade from 2.4.4 to 2.5.1. You can only move to **2.5.2 as next step**.

Refer to this [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html) under section "PostgreSQL version 10.x extensions supported on Amazon RDS".

And similarly if you wanted to go to **3.1.4** from **2.4.4**, you must **first go to 2.5.2 and then to 3.1.4**.

[image: See image for the versions]

Comment: @Vinesh, pls select my answer if it helped.

Answer (score 4):

In order to upgrade to version 2.5.* you need to run the following command

`ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO "2.5.2";`

Comment: As a clarification, this is because AWS RDS supports specific versions of PostgreSQL extensions. In this case, the PostGIS version that is supported for v10 is 2.5.2. This is in this table in the AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.Extensions.101x

Comment: You cannot run this statement on his db as versions over 2.4.4 are not supported.